# Is there a flight search engine that allows me to pick the departure and return flight separately?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-search-engines

I am looking for a specific route, but unfortunately I have many limitations in terms of schedule.
Many search flight search engines give me good options in terms of price but not the ideal combination for time, given my schedule limitations.
Searching on the company website I can see other options but for some reason the flight search engine does not present them.

Is there a search engine that allows me to pick the departure and return separately?

Comment: A) Did you try Kayak? I presume you did. B) If you did, what's missing.

Comment: @chx I did. Maybe I missed that option. I will look again

Comment: Are you looking to purchase a return journey by selecting outward and inward journeys separately?

Comment: Kayak allows this for sure...

Comment: @JoErNanO yes, thats the goal

Comment: Kayak (and several other sites) allow you to checkmark one leg of a round-trip or multi-city itinerary, and then it will filter to use only that flight for that leg.

Comment: Many, I imagine. | http://www.hipmunk.com is useful. | http://www.adioso.com  is fun and often useful.

Answer (score 4):

[`Google Flights`](https://www.google.com/flights/), It will allow you to do specifically what you are asking. Just enter your arrival/departure city and proceed from there as it will list the options for flights.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add [Kayak](https://www.ca.kayak.com/flights?mc=y) to the answers.

Make sure you choose multi-city, under flights and you can pick departure and return separately

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you call the customer service of these flight search engines or the customer service of any travel agency they will help you to book a multi-stop flights.